# Bar chart refreshing each time after changing parameters

Tags: reporting-services

I am facing a problem in my SSRS report for some days-
The Bar Chart is refreshing when the parameters fields like-Month, Country are changed. However the information is in blank after refreshing and we need to click on view report to refreshing properly. The refresh only should happening when click on View Report. I am using Sql server 2008 R2.